# Android SIP, receive call with app closed

Tags: android, sip

i´m working developing a SIP application using Android SIP STACK.
I can make and receive call and get phone ringin without problems when app is open. But, when app is closed no call is received. How can achive this?
My code looks like:

**Register the broadcast in an activity**

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.MakeCallActivity.INCOMING_CALL");
callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);
```

**My Incoming call Receiver**

```
/**
 * Listens for incoming SIP calls, intercepts and hands them off to
 * WalkieTalkieActivity.
 */
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
    private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    /**
     * Processes the incoming call, answers it, and hands it over to the
     * WalkieTalkieActivity.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The context under which the receiver is running.
     * @param intent
     *            The intent being received.
     */

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final MakeCallActivity siActivity = (MakeCallActivity) context;

        try {
            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {

                    // call.answerCall(10);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // Call picked UI
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // Call ended. Back to normal UI
                }
            };

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

            incomingCall = siActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);
            showIncomingCallGui(intent, context);
            siActivity.call = incomingCall;

            // incomingCall = siActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent,
            // listener);
            // incomingCall.answerCall(10);
            // incomingCall.startAudio();
            //
            // siActivity.call = incomingCall;
            siActivity.updateStatus(incomingCall);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (incomingCall != null) {
                incomingCall.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".sip.core.IncomingCallReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver"/>
```

Also i tried with a service but no luck

**My service**

```
public class IncomingCallService extends Service {

    private static IncomingCallReceiver m_CallReceiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        registerCallOffReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(m_CallReceiver);
        m_CallReceiver = null;
    }

    private void registerCallOffReceiver() {
        m_CallReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("Service Para Llamadas", "android.call.INCOMING_CALL");
                // do something, e.g. send Intent to main app

            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.call.INCOMING_CALL");
        registerReceiver(m_CallReceiver, filter);
    }

}
```

And manifest

```
<service
            android:name=".sip.core.IncomingCallService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: How does it show in front end?

Comment: We use an activity that receives a call object and connect the call

Comment: ok. I've done it using Twilio and I can give you logic of that.

Comment: Really. I would greatly appreciate it. Please.  Let me know if u need some thing from me

Comment: Use unBound Service, and call your method in a handler and call that handler inside onStartCommand method and give the return type there Return Sticky to start service again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that would work. I have not tested by myself. However, I have a feeling that it might work.

Check it out this [link](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android) to create a service that never dies, then register your intent to receiver sip calls after the app being killed.